# Celery on linux doesn't fairly dispatch tasks with prefork pool

Tags: python, celery

I encounter strange problem in my celery tasks(or understanding).

Let's start with simple caching task from cookbook:

```
@app.task(name="core.test_dispatching", bind=True)
def test_dispatching(self, *messages):
    import random
    import time

    disk_name_hexdigest = md5(str(hash(messages))).hexdigest()

    lock_id = '{0}-lock-{1}'.format(self.name, disk_name_hexdigest)

    # This snippet from celery cookbook
    acquire_lock = lambda: cache.add(lock_id, 'true', LOCK_EXPIRE)
    release_lock = lambda: cache.delete(lock_id)

    if acquire_lock():
        try:
            time.sleep(random.randint(50, 60))
            logger.info("After sleep got messages: %s", messages)
        finally:
            release_lock()
        return True
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        logger.info("Someone already processing messages!")
        return False
```

This code allows to execute many tasks, but only one will print `messages` (with same arguments).

But with default `prefork` pool on Linux (Fedora22 4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64) dispatching of the tasks is not what I expected.

my celery settings:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
CELERY_DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT = "100/s"
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 20 
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 2
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

test code:

```
for i in range(30): tasks.test_dispatching.delay("hello", "world!")
```

**expected results**: 29 tasks succeed in less than 30 seconds, and one completes after 50-60 seconds.

**actual results**:

1. Fedora22: 8 tasks completes in 50-60 seconds, rest in lesser than 30 seconds.
2. Windows10: 29 tasks succeed in less than 30 seconds, and one completes after 50-60 seconds.

Is something wrong with my setup? Or should I use ThreadPool on linux (-p threads).